# Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

У меня есть сервер, который возвращает html страницу с ресурсами (фотками, стилями и js)

Главный цикл: (прослушивает, на запрос вызывает обработчик)

```
        void StartMainLoop()
        {
            try
            {
                while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    RequestReceived?.Invoke(HttpListener.GetContext());
                }
            }
            catch (HttpListenerException e)
            {
                Logger.Log(LogSeverity.Warning, nameof(Core), "Expected exception on closing sockets.", e);
                HttpListener.Stop();
                HttpListener = new HttpListener();
                configuration.ApiListenAddresses.ForEach(HttpListener.Prefixes.Add);
                configuration.HttpListenAddresses.ForEach(HttpListener.Prefixes.Add);
                HttpListener.Start();
                Logger.Log(LogSeverity.Info, nameof(Core), "Listener recreated.");
            }
        }
```

Обработчик: (находит нужный файл и вызывает отправщика)

```
        public void ExecuteHandler(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            string url = context.Request.RawUrl ?? string.Empty;
            var fileName = url[1..];

            Logger.Log(LogSeverity.Debug, nameof(HttpHandler), fileName);

            if (!SecurityUtilities.ValidateFileName(fileName))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                context.Response.Close();
                return;
            }

            var filesOperator = new FilesOperator(_frontendLocation);
            var fileStream = filesOperator.GetFile(fileName);
            if (fileStream == null)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                return;
            }
            var responseSender = new RawDataResponseSender(fileStream);
            responseSender.Send(context.Response.OutputStream);
            fileStream.Dispose();
            context.Response.Close();
        }
```

Отправщик: (записывает в поток ответа байты файла)

```
    public class RawDataResponseSender
    {
        private readonly Stream data;

        public RawDataResponseSender(Stream data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void Send(Stream outputStream)
        {
            if (!outputStream.CanWrite)
            {
                throw new AccessViolationException();
            }
            data.CopyTo(outputStream);
            outputStream.Flush();
            data.Close();
        }
    }
```

Весь сайт нормально загружается, но на последнем файле (favicon.ico) сервер падает с ошибкой

```
System.Net.HttpListenerException (64): Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно.
   at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
   at YCore.API.IO.RawDataResponseSender.Send(Stream outputStream) in RawDataResponseSender.cs:line 22
   at YCore.HttpHandler.ExecuteHandler(HttpListenerContext context) in HttpHandler.cs:line 51
   at YCore.Core.StartMainLoop() in Core.cs:line 64
```